# How to log memory and cpu usage of an application?

Tags: command-line, cpu-load, logging, memory-usage

Similar to question [How to log CPU load?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22021/how-to-log-cpu-load), I would like to log memory of a process.

The process I want to log, is killed on a remote server, and I want to find out the CPU load and the memory usage just before it was killed.

**[update]**

Both Stefano Palazzo's neat little python script and

Michał's one line output values that are smaller than in `top` for CPU and Mem. Do you have an idea why?

**output top:**

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
2312 schXX     20   0 1241m 328m  58m S  100  0.3  11:56.68 MATLAB
```

**output Stefano Palazzo's python script:**

```
python memlogger.py 2312
%CPU    %MEM
76.00   0.20
76.00   0.20
```

Comment: I unfortunately can't comment here yet but you may find this post of interest expalining why `ps` may differ from `top`:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process

Answer (score 19):

You can create one-liner in shell:

```
logpid() { while sleep 1; do  ps -p $1 -o pcpu= -o pmem= ; done; }
```

to log process with pid=123 just:

```
logpid 123
```

or to see and write log to file:

```
logpid $$ | tee /tmp/pid.log
```

If you want other data to be logged, modify `-o {this}` options. See `man ps` section "STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS" for available parameters to use. If you want different time resolution, change `sleep {this}` in function `logpid()`.

Comment: Simple and does the job!

Answer (score 6):

If you are precisely after the `top` statistics you could run `top` in batch mode specifying the pid of the process that you are after. Taking the example from this page (http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-cool-hacks.html) if you typed

```
top -b -d 10 -n 3 >> top-file
```

You would "have top running in batch mode (-b). It's going to refresh every 10 seconds, as specified by the delay (-d) flag, for a total count of 3 iterations (-n). The output will be sent to a file." Including `-p` you can specify the `pid` of the process that you are after. This will of course return more than purely cpu and ram but it will contain thos fields. In my case for example I would get the following when monitoring pid 9189 using `top -b -d 10 -n 3 -p 9189 >> ~/top-file`:

```
PID  USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
9189 pmj27     20   0 1617016 808112  27916 S   0.0  0.3   1:36.63 gedit
```

Comment: This page, though it doesn't do redirections to a file, does carry out some more sophisitcated modifications allowing you to obtain only CPU printed out. If you someone knows of a good way to redirect the output to a file and have it update periodically I'd be interested to know. `watch` doesn't seem ideal to me for this:
http://superuser.com/questions/281347/filtering-top-command-output

Answer (score 3):

This simple python script should do what you want:

```py
import time
import string
import sys
import commands

def get_cpumem(pid):
    d = [i for i in commands.getoutput("ps aux").split("\n")
        if i.split()[1] == str(pid)]
    return (float(d[0].split()[2]), float(d[0].split()[3])) if d else None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not len(sys.argv) == 2 or not all(i in string.digits for i in sys.argv[1]):
        print("usage: %s PID" % sys.argv[0])
        exit(2)
    print("%CPU\t%MEM")
    try:
        while True:
            x,y = get_cpumem(sys.argv[1])
            if not x:
                print("no such process")
                exit(1)
            print("%.2f\t%.2f" % (x,y))
            time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print
        exit(0)
```

You first need to find out the process id of the program you want to monitor, then you can run the script with the PID as an argument:

```
python log.py 3912
```

It will print the cpu usage and ram usage in per cent two times a second:

```
%CPU    %MEM
0.90    0.40
1.43    0.40
8.21    0.40
...
```

You can then redirect its output to a file in order to import it into a spreadsheet later (`python log.py 9391 > firefox_log.txt`) and import the data into a spreadsheet selecting `Tab` as your separator.

The program quits when you hit Ctrl+C or when the process is killed.

Comment: Dear Stefano, thank you very much for your script. Unfortunately it seems to output wrong results. Do you have any idea why? Please see my updated question.

Comment: From the ps man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html , ps outputs the "CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio), expressed as a percentage" - so you get an average of the CPU usage since it started

Answer (score 1):

[Procpath](https://pypi.org/project/Procpath/) can be used to record Procfs metrics of an application (process trees) including CPU usage and Resident Set Size (RSS). Full disclosure: I wrote it.

Let's take Firefox as an example. On my machine its process tree looks like this:

```
 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 ├─ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 4 ...
 ├─ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 ...
 ├─ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 ...
 ├─ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 ...
 ├─ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID ...
 ├─ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID ...
 └─ /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 8 ...
```

Wit Procpath you can collect process metrics from this tree like the following (and see [the documentation](https://procpath.readthedocs.io/) if want to ask your allication's process supervisor, say systemd or Docker, for the root PID):

```
procpath record -d firefox.sqlite '$..children[?(@.stat.comm == "firefox")]'
```

With this command Procpath will collect and record this tree's Procfs metrics once per 10 seconds. You can leave it running in a terminal multiplexor (like Byobu) to run it in the background on your server.

When your application crashes again, you can use this command to visualise CPU usage and resident set size of the application.

```
procpath plot -d firefox.sqlite -f firefox.svg -q cpu -q rss --formatter=integer
```

[image: CPU vs RSS plot]