# monitor memory usage of a single process in Ubuntu

Tags: memory-usage

Do you know How to monitor memory usage of a single process?

I want to get Memory usage over a given time frame including **maximum usage** and **average usage**.

Don't tell me use `top -p PID`, since I cannot stare the screen for hours to check the maximum memory usage.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56266/how-to-log-memory-and-cpu-usage-of-an-application

Comment: Don't have my linux box avail. atm so can't be specific but look at `pidstat `which is in the `sysstat` package. Run `man pidstat` to see options & at bottom some example commands. You can output to a log & if desired just minimize the terminal for longer term monitoring

Answer (score 2):

Install sysstat package

Read `man pidstat`, look at option &  for example commands go to bottom of man page.

Ex. of nautilus, current id here as reported by ps is 2286, generating 120 reports 60 secs apart, outputting to a log in home folder

Get process id you want to track, many ways, a couple below - (start process/app

find in list

`ps axu`

If you know the name then this works fine, current example of nautilus

`ps axu |grep nautilus |grep -v grep`

Then in a terminal, (replacing your process # after -p

`pidstat -r -p 2286 60 120 > naut-mem.log`

If desired just minimize terminal while pidstat is running

If you plan on outputting to same log file several times & want it appended to then use >> instead of > in command